# django allauth adapter signup: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django and Allauth. I need the user to be able to signup with additional field, so I created a custom user call Profile, a custom SignupForm and an Adapter, but when I submit I get the error "**save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'**".

custom form

```
 class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
        first_name = forms.CharField(
            max_length=200,
            label='Nome*',
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Il tuo nome'}),
            required=True
        )
        last_name = forms.CharField(
            max_length=200,
            label='Cognome*',
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Il tuo cognome'}),
            required=True
        )

        etc...

        def signup(self, request, user):
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
            user.cap = self.cleaned_data['cap']
            user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
            user.province = self.cleaned_data['province']
            user.state = self.cleaned_data['state']
            user.pi = self.cleaned_data['pi']
            user.cf = self.cleaned_data['cf']
            user.save()
```

adapter

```
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.email = data['email']
        user.first_name = data['first_name']
        user.last_name = data['last_name']
        user.address = data.get('address')
        user.cap = data['cap']
        user.city = data['city']
        user.province = data['province']
        user.state = data['state']
        user.pi = data['pi']
        user.cf = data['cf']
        if 'password1' in data:
            user.set_password(data['password1'])
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()
        self.populate_username(request, user)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

custom user model (Profile)

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    cap = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    pi = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    cf = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    instagram_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    facebook_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    soundcloud_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    credits = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

settings.py

```
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
    ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
    ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
    ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles.Profile'
    ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'main.adapter.AccountAdapter'

    ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
        'signup': 'main.forms.CustomSignupForm',
    }
```

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `save` method on your form class:

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
# ...
    def save(self, user):
        user.save()
```

Comment: now I get: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'save'